# Java references not updated

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("a");
strings.add("b");
strings.add("c");

for (String s : strings) {
    s = new String("x");
}

System.err.println(strings);
```

which prints [a, b, c]

I thought it would print [x, x, x] because I iterate over the Strings, which returns a reference to a String Object. In the loop I assign a new Object to the reference, accordingly s should point to the new String Object?

Where is my fault?

What is the best way to update the strings in my array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the loop I assign a new Object to the reference

Well, you assign a new reference as the value for `s`. `s` is just a local variable though, which was initialized with the value of the element. It's not tied to the element in the list though - that was just how it was initialized. It's a bit like changing the value of a method parameter - that doesn't change whatever variable was used as an argument:

```
void method(String y) {
    y = "bar"; // This doesn't change x.
}
...

String x = "foo";
method(x);
System.out.println(x); // foo
```

If you want to update the strings in your list (not an array - it's worth being clear about the difference) you should use a regular `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    strings.set(i, "x");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It prints "a b c " because you are not changing(adding) anything in the list.

for (String s : strings) {
        s = new String("x"); 
    }

The above code can be read as :

*For each* `String s` in `List strings` **set s to a new String value "x"**. You are not doing anything to the list. You get the value from the list, store it in `s` and overwrite `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You only change the value of the local `s` variable, not the elements in the `List`.

You can change elements in the list by `List.set(int index, E element)`.

Answer (score 1):

`s` you specified here has scope only in the `for` loop

```
 for (String s : strings) {
                s = new String("x");
            }
```

value of new `String` object is passed to `s` on each iteration, but `strings` is not getting affected at all.